# What is better, cache data from microsoft graph or just hit the microsoft graph api with each search?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am using Microsoft graph, I need to get users data from Azure AD.  The scnario is when user type the user name in the textbox and name started to poup on the fly for Autocomplete textbox.  Now I am thinking what is the better approach should I hit the Microsoft grpah api wiht each search or shoud at firt cache the data and let autocomplete textbox work from the cache.
I am looking for answer is to why should I not directly hit the api each time, what benefit I would have to cache the data.  If I hit the api each time at least I wont have to go through the paging and store the data at first in the cache or session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your application should ideally make calls to Microsoft Graph to retrieve data in real-time as necessary. You should only cache or store data locally if required for a specific scenario, and if that use case is covered by your terms of use and privacy policy, and does not violate the Microsoft APIs Terms of Use. Your application should also implement proper retention and deletion policies.

Refer Best practices [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/best-practices-concept?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0#storing-data-locally)

Also, you can explore [Microsoft Graph toolkit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/toolkit/overview?view=graph-rest-1.0) and see if this helps ease your development in any way.

Comment: Shweta, thanks for your answer.  Actually I need to store the data since it is large set of data which doesn't change often and we need to get it frequently so it make sense to keep it local for the session of the application.

Comment: yes in that case.